# jQuery and mouseover issue

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('a.home-page-link').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity:    0.4
        }, 200, function());
    });
```

For some reason, this refuses to "play ball", any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: could you post your html? edit: ok no need ^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding {} to the second function

```
$('a.home-page-link').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity:    0.4
        }, 200, function() { } );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.home-page-link').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity:    0.4
        }, 200, function(){});
    });
```

make sure your callback function is declared correctly. then it should work. test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5XwKG/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just forgot to paste something but the third argument to `.animate()` - `function()` will throw an error as there is no function body defined: `function() {}` or just leave that last argument off might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the callback function, leave it out:

```
$('a.home-page-link').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.4
    }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this? It works for me...

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{   
        $('a.home-page-link').mouseover(function() 
        {
            $(this).animate({opacity:0.4}, 200);
        });       
});
```